# Javascript: read from URL

Tags: javascript

I use the following to read variables from a URL:

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}
```

The URLs in question are set like this:

```
<a href="View?wl_id=' + i.event_id + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(i.event_title) + '">
```

I have an example URL which is:

```
...&title=New%20clothes!
```

To see it I `alert(decodeURIComponent($.urlParam('title')));` which shows `New Clothes!` - perfect

I have another example which is:

```
...&title=Favorite%20Fragrances
```

This when alerted shows **`F`** - that's it

Another example:

```
...&title=private%20testing
```

When alerted produces **`0`**

Any ideas why they don't all produce what they should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&amp;` is not correct. Use `&` instead.